# How can I avoid loading an assembly dynamically that I have already loaded using Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am loading assemblies using Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFilePath) in a loop and I want to avoid calling Assembly.LoadFile if the assembly has already be loaded once.  Should I be concerned about calling Assembly.LoadFile repeatedly for a DLL that has already been loaded?  Thanks.

Comment: Load() and LoadFile() loads assembiles into different contexts. Why do you use LoadFile() if they are in a folder that would be found simply by assembly name? See these articles: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No you don't need to be concerned because if an assembly has already been loaded it won't be loaded again

If you call Assembly.LoadFile() then you can load the same assembly multiple times but only if you are loading assembly from different path each time. You can use [Assembly.Load()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will load an assembly only once. You can also find about already loaded assemblies in current app domain using

```
Assembly[] asms = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

Comment: And it seems that Assembly.LoadFile is at least as efficient at figuring out that the assembly is loaded (probably more efficient) than manually enumerating through AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().

Answer (score 0):

For the given AppDomain, you can call [`GetAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx) and see if it's loaded.